# How to edit ES File Explorer default view

Tags: es-file-explorer

The **Home Page** of **ES File Explorer** is shown as 
[image]

I want **Home Page** as a default view, when I open **ES File Explorer**.

I tried to change from here.
[image]

But it's not changed.
Pls let me know, how to change it?

Regards
Smith

Comment: What version of ES File Explorer are you using? Can you edit the post and insert an image to show the default view that you have currently?

Comment: Its ES File Explorer Pro version and the path you see in Home directory appears by default when I open ES File Explorer.